# Nginx + Next.js error_page

Tags: authentication, nginx, next.js, jwt

I have nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;

     
        #                                                                                        AUTHENTICATION
        error_page 401 /login;


        location = /auth {
            internal;

            proxy_pass http://localhost:3333;

            proxy_pass_request_body off;
            proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
            proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Original-Remote-Addr $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Original-Host $host;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
        }

        location ~ ^/(login|signin|logout|get-user) {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Original-Remote-Addr $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Original-Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3333;
        }


        location / {
            auth_request /auth;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:1000;
        }
    }
}
```

And second service (localhost:3333), that contains next.js login page(localhost:3333/login) and auth request method (localhost:3333/auth).

When I try to hit `localhost/foo` -> I see next.js login page as expected,
but when I try something like `localhost/foo?bar=1` -> I see next.js login page, but the url just after a moment changes to `localhost/login/foo?bar=1`.

My next.js login app has baseUrl /login. If I replace next.js login page in nginx.conf with `return 200 'please, login'`, url doesn't change. So, I think next.js changes the url.